# strange template problem

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have the following function defined:

```
template<class KEY, class VALUE, class HASH_FUNCTION, 
         class COMPARATOR_FUNCTION, class GREATER_THAN_FUNCTION>
bool Test3(size_t szCount, double dLoadFactor, vector<KEY>& vVals, 
           const HASH_FUNCTION& hf, const COMPARATOR_FUNCTION& cf, 
           const GREATER_THAN_FUNCTION& gf)
```

Then I call it in `main()`.

```
int main()
{
    vector<char*> vVals = GetWords("enwik8", 128*1024*1024);
    SHash sh;
    SHComp cf;
    SHGreater gf;
    Test3(1000, 0.7f, vVals, sh, cf, gf);

    return 0;
}
```

And I get this error thrown at me:

```
/home/duminda/main.cpp:313: error: no matching function for call to 
    ‘Test3(int, float, std::vector<char*, std::allocator<char*> >&, SHash&, 
    SHComp&, SHGreater&)’
```

I maybe missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How is VALUE being used in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the function declaration, it has a template parameter `V` which isn't used anywhere in the actual parameter list. So it can't be deduced automatically at the call site.

Try just defining it as this instead:

```
template<class K class HF, class CF, class GF>
bool Test3(size_t szCount, double dLoadFactor, vector<K>& vVals, const HF& hf, const CF& cf, const GF& gf)
```

By the way, you might want to consider spending 5 seconds coming up with meaningful names. If `V` had had a sensible name, it might have been more obvious that it serves no purpose.

Comment: `V` is used by the function `Test3`. Is there a way for me to tell the compiler what the type of `V` is?

Comment: This does not make sense, is it used in Comparator? Maybe Comparator can have a value_type? You must get the items from somewhere to compare. If it is because you want to return it, you can pass in all the template arguments, or have a V& output

Comment: @nakiya: You can make `VALUE` the first parameter in the list and explicitly specify it's type in the call: `Test3<Type_Of_Value>(args)`.

Comment: +1 for the comment on using meaningful template parameter names. Far too often developers do that in most of their code but when it comes to template parameters it's single-letter...

Comment: @CashCow: Well, single-letter template type names are often ok. If you just have a single type, then `T` is a pretty common convention, especially if the type plays no special role (like in `std::vector`, for example) But when you have to keep track of 5 different types and they actually represent specific concepts (in this case, they seem to be hash functions and comparers), then a meaningful name can be a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

There is a template parameter VALUE that has not been resolved. It is never used.

Your function should already be able to derive this type if it is using it somewhere in the body. If it derives from a different template parameter, ensure you have a way of doing so. Possibly that template parameter has an internal typedef, for example if one of your comparison functions compares values of this type, they could have a value_type typedef.

Be certain to use typename in the body to get to this type if it is done that way.

Answer (score 1):

Given the edited declaration

```
template<class KEY, class VALUE, class HASH_FUNCTION,
         class COMPARATOR_FUNCTION, class GREATER_THAN_FUNCTION>
bool Test3(size_t szCount, double dLoadFactor, vector<KEY>& vVals,
           const HASH_FUNCTION& hf, const COMPARATOR_FUNCTION& cf,
           const GREATER_THAN_FUNCTION& gf);
```

and the comment: `V` is used by the function Test3. Is there a way for me to tell the compiler what the type of `V` is?

The problem with `Test3(1000, 0.7f, vVals, sh, cf, gf);` is that the compiler cannot deduce the template argument `VALUE`.  But you can explicitly list template arguments to a function name like this:

```
Test3<const char*, value_type>(1000, 0.7f, vVals, sh, cf, gf);
```

Here the first two template arguments `KEY`=`const char*` and `VALUE`=`value_type` are given in `<` angle brackets `>`, and the rest can be deduced by the compiler.

If you change the order of `KEY` and `VALUE` in the template declaration, you could skip providing the `KEY` and let that be deduced:

```
template<class VALUE, class KEY, class HASH_FUNCTION,
         class COMPARATOR_FUNCTION, class GREATER_THAN_FUNCTION>
bool Test3(size_t szCount, double dLoadFactor, vector<KEY>& vVals,
           const HASH_FUNCTION& hf, const COMPARATOR_FUNCTION& cf,
           const GREATER_THAN_FUNCTION& gf);

// ...

Test3<value_type>(1000, 0.7f, vVals, sh, cf, gf);
```